# Google app engine python doesn't read js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, google-app-engine

I built a python app on google app engine that pulls pictures from the flickr API and allows users to do cool stuff with the pictures, like drag and drop.

I have three JS files in the body:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/init.js"></script>
```

My jQuery code is working fine but only when I write it in either of the jQuery documents. If I place the code in the init.js, the code simply doesn't work, which I find rather weird. I  put the code in the jquery files because I wrote console logs on the three script files and only the init.js didn't print to the console. I am linking the files correctly and referring to the right folder and right file. The folder JS was also added to the app.yaml:

```
- url: /js
  static_dir: js
```

I can just leave the code in the jQuery file but this is not what I am supposed to do. I want to fix it.Is there a specific way to use the JS file on google app engine?

Comment: I suggest you fully qualify your paths, or set base in the document.  If you page is "/some_view/"  then the js will be loaded from "/some_view/js/init.js".  e.g `<script src="/js/init.js">`  If this is happening you will 404 errors in your logs.

Comment: In other words, make sure you put a leading slash in your path.  That sets it to be found from the root, and not the current url.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs, guys. It started working now and I didn't change anything. I have no idea why it didn't work before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it. The problem was that I named the file init.js. For some reason Firefox doesn't like that name (at least mine didn't) and didn't load the file. Chrome loaded the file without any problems. When I changed the file name to main.js, it started working in Firefix as well. I only tried this when I had exhausted all other possible options though. Such a weird behavior of Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute paths instead of relative when loading your JS files (add the leading slash `/`):

```
<script src="/js/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/jquery-ui-1.10.4.custom.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/init.js"></script>
```